# Sibling game objects not colliding in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a game in which waves of enemies are spawned by storing an arrangement of enemies as children of an empty game object, which I can then save as a prefab and instantiate with an enemy spawner script, but there is no collision between the enemies, and the only reason I can think of is because of some physics optimization due to them being siblings.
 These are my collider and rigidbody settings for the enemies: 
 [image]
 Any idea why this happens? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because your Rigidbody constraints are set to freeze movement on both the X and Y axes:

[image]

This means that any movement you would normally expect from simulated physical interactions (for example, changing velocity from colliding with another enemy) will be ignored for this Rigidbody. See [the Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-constraints.html) for more details on what they do.

The simple fix here would be to uncheck those checkboxes, so that you rely on the physics system to handle these interactions. If you want to fully control them through code though, you could technically write code in `OnCollisionEnter()` to handle the collision between two enemies - but that would be a much more involved solution.